# Need AngularJS advice on dynamically loading friendlist chat for a unique user?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let me explain further, take this image for a friendlist:

[image]

Everytime I click on  a unique friend, I want to go to the actual conversation page between me and the user as shown below.

[image]

I'm pretty new to angular so please explain to me how I can achieve such things on the front end. I just need to write the front-end controller, services and all other front-end angular essentials for it and the back-end developer will connect it to his back-end. I guess i need to know the most on how can one friend that gets click on contain the information to that specific chat conversation.

Comment: try something. If you are totally blank, try the angularjs chatroom...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your project into below architecture:
1. FriendListController: This will hold the list of all friends, as shown in image 1
2. ChatController: This is the actual chat between youa and selected user.

The route configuration for both the controllers will be done as below:

```js
angular
  .module('app', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/friendslist', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/FriendsList.html',
      controller: 'FriendsListController'
    })
    .when('friendslist/:friendId/chat', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/Chat.html',
      controller: 'ChatController'
    })
    .otherwise('/friendslist')
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Now when you select the friend in FriendsList view, just redirect the user to chat with friendId of selected friend as:

```js
$location.path('friendslist/'+ selectedFriendId + '/chat');
```

With the above route configuration and redirect logic, you should be able to achieve the required behavi